# How to cancel a call with RxJava2?

Tags: android, retrofit, rx-java2

I'm using RxJava2 and Retrofit. In my fragment, I make a request to upload a local file:

```
Disposable disposable = mApi.requestUpload(file)
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        .subscribe(response -> {
            toast("success");
        }, throwable -> {
            toast("failed");
        });
mCompositeDisposable.add(disposable);
```

Then, clear all disposables in `onDestroyView()`

```
@Override
public void onDestroyView() {
    mCompositeDisposable.clear();
    super.onDestroyView();
}
```

But I use **Charles** to view all requests and find that **the request is still executing after I finish the fragment**. **The file is still uploaded successfully after a time**.

How can I cancel the call when fragment closed?

Comment: What Retrofit version are you using. Sounds like Retrofit doesn't cancel the upload properly.

Comment: Retrofit version 2.4.0

Comment: @EbnZhang did you check my answer?

Answer (score 1):

use `disposable.dipose()` for canceling your call.

Comment: `mCompositeDisposable.clear();` should dispose and clear all `Disposable`s added. I'm pretty sure that `disposable.dispose()` is called.

Answer (score 1):

1. Define Disposable

   `private  io.reactivex.disposables.Disposable mDisposable;`
2. assign to your service

   ```
   mService.getResults(query)
               .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.from(Looper.getMainLooper(), true))
               .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
               .subscribe(new SingleObserver<Response<Model>>() {
                   @Override
                   public void onSubscribe(Disposable d) {
                       /* required */
                       mDisposable = d;
                   }

                   @Override
                   public void onSuccess(Response<Model> response) {
                       dismissProgress();
                   }

                   @Override
                   public void onError(Throwable e) {

                   }
               });
   ```
3. call below line to dismiss/terminate ongoing API call

   ```
    if (mDisposable != null)
       mDisposable.dispose();
   ```

There you go.

**UPDATE**

in your case, it should be

```
@Override
public void onDestroyView() {
if (mCompositeDisposable!= null) // in case if you required-> if (mCompositeDisposable!= null && !mCompositeDisposable.isDisposed())
      mCompositeDisposable.dispose(); 
super.onDestroyView();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I already use code like your answer, but still not work. Dispose all Disposable only unsubscribe the result of current call, but not really stop uploading file. And I found that cancel a Http call is not reliable, so maybe my question is not about RxJava......

Comment: @EbnZhang in this case https://futurestud.io/tutorials/retrofit-2-cancel-requests.

Answer (score 0):

Add RxJava to CompositeDisposable
Then in onStop()
use disposableRxJava.dispose()